# Download Gradle dependencies with ".modules" files

Tags: maven, gradle, groovy

I currently have an offline environment where I have all my dependencies (jar, aar & pom files). The thing is that I want to use Coil (image library) as a dependency in my Android project. This library requires `kotlinx-coroutines-core` to be also downloaded in my environment. I have been able to download all the required files except for `.module` file (Gradle Module Metadata), which is necessary because there are multiple variants of `kotlinx-coroutines-core` (versions for the JVM, JS and Native).

In other words, my code downloads `kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.3.9.jar` (with its POM) and `kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.3.9.pom` which is great but `kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.3.9.module` file is still missing and not sure how can I download it.

Here is my code based on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bmuschko/e4e04abca105c397145e):

```
task copyDependencies() {
    def name = "default"
    def configuration = configurations.getByName(name)
    copyJars(configuration)
    copyPoms(configuration)
}

private void copyJars(Configuration configuration) {
    File repoDir = new File(project.buildDir, 'repository')

    configuration.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.each { artifact ->
        def moduleVersionId = artifact.moduleVersion.id
        File moduleDir = new File(repoDir, "${moduleVersionId.group.replace('.', '/')}/${moduleVersionId.name}/${moduleVersionId.version}")
        GFileUtils.mkdirs(moduleDir)
        GFileUtils.copyFile(artifact.file, new File(moduleDir, artifact.file.name))
    }
}

private void copyPoms(Configuration configuration) {

    def componentIds = configuration.incoming.resolutionResult.allDependencies.collect { it.selected.id }

    def result = project.dependencies.createArtifactResolutionQuery()
            .forComponents(componentIds)
            .withArtifacts(MavenModule, MavenPomArtifact)
            .execute()

    for (component in result.resolvedComponents) {
        def componentId = component.id

        if (componentId instanceof ModuleComponentIdentifier) {
            File repoDir = new File(project.buildDir, 'repository')
            File moduleDir = new File(repoDir, "${componentId.group.replace('.', '/')}/${componentId.module}/${componentId.version}")
            GFileUtils.mkdirs(moduleDir)
            File pomFile = component.getArtifacts(MavenPomArtifact)[0].file

            GFileUtils.copyFile(pomFile, new File(moduleDir, pomFile.name))
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is: How can I download `.module` files when downloading my dependencies? An example would be downloading this [file](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-core/1.3.9/kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.3.9.module).

Answer (score -1):

To copy a configuration's files to a directory, you can do this:

```
task copyLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.runtimeClasspath
    into file("$buildDir/repository")
}
```

This will copy everything including transitive dependencies.

Not need to write all that code yourself. Why do you want POMs and all that in your application's classpath? Just let Gradle sort it out for you.

Comment: Not sure if I've explained myself. My goal here is creating an offline gradle repository where multiple projects can point to and get their dependencies. I'm working in an offline environment without internet access (company secuity policy) so I'm trying to create my own version of a maven repository with a few dependencies.
Without the POM files, gradle complains about them missing and it is unable to resolve dependencies.
This setup is currently working fine except when having dependencies that depend on Gradle Module Metadata files (in this case it's a transitive dependency).

Comment: What you need to do is basically resolve the dependencies when you have internet available, and then copy the Gradle dependency cache to whatever environment you need it. Gradle can run in offline mode, in which case it should only use the cached dependencies... what you're trying to do is difficult and unreliable. If offline builds don't work, maybe check [this plugin](https://gitlab.com/ysb33rOrg/ivypot-gradle-plugin) that can do this for you.